# What Format is the following string?

Tags: php, soap

I am busy with a SOAP Call to a webservice and one of the parameters specify that I need to pass a unique identifier in this format - 3254042a-a3be-445f-8690-98be2b5d27cd... What does this mean?? Is that not an example of the format that was not mentioned? If anyone can tell me what format this is, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier

Comment: Thank you. So effectively passing ${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()} to the webservice in this parameter should work?

Comment: Its a GUID and typically used as an identifier in request. Can be very useful when tracing/debugging messages on a large and busy ESB.